# using retrofit with Cookie persistence

Tags: java, android, session-cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x, retrofit

I guys, I'm using retrofit and I wonder how to transparently handle the session cookie.
For that I extend the given ApacheClient and use a CookieStore in the custom call to ApacheClient.execute(HttpClient, HttpUriRequest) :

```
Client client = new ApacheClient() {
    final CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    @Override
    protected HttpResponse execute(HttpClient client, HttpUriRequest request) throws IOException {
        // BasicHttpContext is not thread safe 
        // CookieStore is thread safe
        BasicHttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
        return client.execute(request, httpContext);
    }
};

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setServer(API_URL)
    .setClient(client)
    .build();
```

Is there a better way to do this with the build-in retrofit API (with no HttpClient extension) ?

Comment: Did this answer somehow helped you?

Comment: no I need a cross HTTP-implementation solution using retrofit API if it exists / but not an Android one...

Comment: You ever figure out how to implement the cookie?

Comment: I'm still using BasicCookieStore with ApacheClient but using colriot answer is better as you can use Okhttp from square (https://github.com/square/okhttp)

Answer (score 13):

Starting from API 9 you have `java.net.CookieManager` and can set system-wide cookie handler like this:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Yes, Apache Http client uses its own cookie-handling mechanism. But it should not be the problem because starting from API 9 HttpURLConnection is recommended HTTP client. 
If you use Retrofit from Square you may also like their OkHttp lib - custom URLConnection implementation with lots of useful capabilities.

Comment: Can you use this with retrofit, If I call this, on my login fragment, can I expect every call made from retrofit to automatically have the cookie attached?

Comment: @Lion789 yes, you can. But it's better to place this code into your custom `Application` successor.

Comment: by application successor what are you referring to exactly? i.e. this is what I was trying to do...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425993/how-to-retrieve-cookies-in-android-retrofit --- also, for the accept_all is it better to let it be the default only the original server or that will not let me get the cookie and if it does, then do I need to do anything extra, because from what I understand I can leave that line out since it is defaulted to that?

Comment: @Lion789 I mean subclass of `Application` class. For example, in its `onCreate` method.

Comment: This worked for me, apparently without this OkHttp won't save any cookies that are requested to be set by the server(Set-Cookie header), but you need to remember to use one single http client instance, I solved that using Singleton with the help of dagger.

Comment: Does this persist cookies across app restarts?