# Using Cookies with Robospice Retrofit requests

Tags: android, session, cookies, retrofit, robospice

Can anyone please suggest me a way to manage cookies in robospice retrofit type HTTP requests.

I have a authentication system which has a login , a few GET HTTP requests , and a logout.

During login i need to save the session and use the same session for the rest GET HTTP requests and when I logout the session has to be cleared.

Here the login is a HTTP POST request which sends and recieves data through JSON format. I am using robospice retrofit as it easily manages the login and logout requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set system-wide cookie-handler via `java.net.CookieManager`

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

in your custom `Application` class.

To clear cookies after logout you can use method like this

```
public void clearCookies() {
    cookieManager.getCookieStore().removeAll();
}
```

Comment: It works only for API >= 9 right ? I need the support for Android API 8 also

Comment: @RevanthGopi yeah, that's right. You can check API level at runtime (as Retrofit does) and work with `java.net.CookieManager`'s cookie management for API >= 9, and with Apache's `BasicCookieStore` for API < 9. See this question for one possible way of using `BasicCookieStore`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894540/using-retrofit-with-cookie-persistence