# Persistent Cookie store using okhttp 2 on Android

Tags: android, cookies, okhttp

In my Android app, I am trying to switch from `android-async-http` to `okhttp` which supports async networking sind version 2.0. While the former ships with an implementation of a [persistent cookie storage](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/PersistentCookieStore.html), I don't know how to implement something like this for `okhttp`.

In my app I have a login routine during which a `get` request is sent that, if successful, should set a cookie. This cookie should be appended to all subsequent network requests and should survive application restarts.

I found [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894540/using-retrofit-with-cookie-persistence) on SO, indicating that the following piece of code, if executed somewhere in the app, activates persistent cookie management and `okhttp` would use it:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

However, for me it does not work. Is the `CookieManager` the right way to go? How could I monitor which cookies were set and stored to further debug the issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Putting the code into a custom `Application`'s `onCreate` function solves the issue. It works now.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // enable cookies
        java.net.CookieManager cookieManager = new java.net.CookieManager();
        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    }
}
```

---

I managed to get persistent cookies with `okhttp` with the following `CookieStore`, which is partly copied from the one of `android-async-http`. It works with API lvl 9 and maybe fewer.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

/**
 * A persistent cookie store which implements the Apache HttpClient CookieStore interface.
 * Cookies are stored and will persist on the user's device between application sessions since they
 * are serialized and stored in SharedPreferences. Instances of this class are
 * designed to be used with AsyncHttpClient#setCookieStore, but can also be used with a
 * regular old apache HttpClient/HttpContext if you prefer.
 */
public class PersistentCookieStore implements CookieStore {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "PersistentCookieStore";
    private static final String COOKIE_PREFS = "CookiePrefsFile";
    private static final String COOKIE_NAME_PREFIX = "cookie_";

    private final HashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpCookie>> cookies;
    private final SharedPreferences cookiePrefs;

    /**
     * Construct a persistent cookie store.
     *
     * @param context Context to attach cookie store to
     */
    public PersistentCookieStore(Context context) {
        cookiePrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(COOKIE_PREFS, 0);
        cookies = new HashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpCookie>>();

        // Load any previously stored cookies into the store
        Map<String, ?> prefsMap = cookiePrefs.getAll();
        for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : prefsMap.entrySet()) {
            if (((String)entry.getValue()) != null && !((String)entry.getValue()).startsWith(COOKIE_NAME_PREFIX)) {
                String[] cookieNames = TextUtils.split((String)entry.getValue(), ",");
                for (String name : cookieNames) {
                    String encodedCookie = cookiePrefs.getString(COOKIE_NAME_PREFIX + name, null);
                    if (encodedCookie != null) {
                        HttpCookie decodedCookie = decodeCookie(encodedCookie);
                        if (decodedCookie != null) {
                            if(!cookies.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
                                cookies.put(entry.getKey(), new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpCookie>());
                            cookies.get(entry.getKey()).put(name, decodedCookie);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
        String name = getCookieToken(uri, cookie);

        // Save cookie into local store, or remove if expired
        if (!cookie.hasExpired()) {
            if(!cookies.containsKey(uri.getHost()))
                cookies.put(uri.getHost(), new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpCookie>());
            cookies.get(uri.getHost()).put(name, cookie);
        } else {
            if(cookies.containsKey(uri.toString()))
                cookies.get(uri.getHost()).remove(name);
        }

        // Save cookie into persistent store
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsWriter = cookiePrefs.edit();
        prefsWriter.putString(uri.getHost(), TextUtils.join(",", cookies.get(uri.getHost()).keySet()));
        prefsWriter.putString(COOKIE_NAME_PREFIX + name, encodeCookie(new SerializableHttpCookie(cookie)));
        prefsWriter.commit();
    }

    protected String getCookieToken(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
        return cookie.getName() + cookie.getDomain();
    }

    @Override
    public List<HttpCookie> get(URI uri) {
        ArrayList<HttpCookie> ret = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
        if(cookies.containsKey(uri.getHost()))
            ret.addAll(cookies.get(uri.getHost()).values());
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsWriter = cookiePrefs.edit();
        prefsWriter.clear();
        prefsWriter.commit();
        cookies.clear();
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean remove(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
        String name = getCookieToken(uri, cookie);

        if(cookies.containsKey(uri.getHost()) && cookies.get(uri.getHost()).containsKey(name)) {
            cookies.get(uri.getHost()).remove(name);

            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsWriter = cookiePrefs.edit();
            if(cookiePrefs.contains(COOKIE_NAME_PREFIX + name)) {
                prefsWriter.remove(COOKIE_NAME_PREFIX + name);
            }
            prefsWriter.putString(uri.getHost(), TextUtils.join(",", cookies.get(uri.getHost()).keySet()));
            prefsWriter.commit();

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {
        ArrayList<HttpCookie> ret = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
        for (String key : cookies.keySet())
            ret.addAll(cookies.get(key).values());

        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public List<URI> getURIs() {
        ArrayList<URI> ret = new ArrayList<URI>();
        for (String key : cookies.keySet())
            try {
                ret.add(new URI(key));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Serializes Cookie object into String
     *
     * @param cookie cookie to be encoded, can be null
     * @return cookie encoded as String
     */
    protected String encodeCookie(SerializableHttpCookie cookie) {
        if (cookie == null)
            return null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
            outputStream.writeObject(cookie);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "IOException in encodeCookie", e);
            return null;
        }

        return byteArrayToHexString(os.toByteArray());
    }

    /**
     * Returns cookie decoded from cookie string
     *
     * @param cookieString string of cookie as returned from http request
     * @return decoded cookie or null if exception occured
     */
    protected HttpCookie decodeCookie(String cookieString) {
        byte[] bytes = hexStringToByteArray(cookieString);
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        HttpCookie cookie = null;
        try {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
            cookie = ((SerializableHttpCookie) objectInputStream.readObject()).getCookie();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "IOException in decodeCookie", e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ClassNotFoundException in decodeCookie", e);
        }

        return cookie;
    }

    /**
     * Using some super basic byte array &lt;-&gt; hex conversions so we don't have to rely on any
     * large Base64 libraries. Can be overridden if you like!
     *
     * @param bytes byte array to be converted
     * @return string containing hex values
     */
    protected String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
        for (byte element : bytes) {
            int v = element & 0xff;
            if (v < 16) {
                sb.append('0');
            }
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
        }
        return sb.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    }

    /**
     * Converts hex values from strings to byte arra
     *
     * @param hexString string of hex-encoded values
     * @return decoded byte array
     */
    protected byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

The `SerializableHttpCookie.java`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.HttpCookie;

public class SerializableHttpCookie implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6374381323722046732L;

    private transient final HttpCookie cookie;
    private transient HttpCookie clientCookie;

    public SerializableHttpCookie(HttpCookie cookie) {
        this.cookie = cookie;
    }

    public HttpCookie getCookie() {
        HttpCookie bestCookie = cookie;
        if (clientCookie != null) {
            bestCookie = clientCookie;
        }
        return bestCookie;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(cookie.getName());
        out.writeObject(cookie.getValue());
        out.writeObject(cookie.getComment());
        out.writeObject(cookie.getCommentURL());
        out.writeObject(cookie.getDomain());
        out.writeLong(cookie.getMaxAge());
        out.writeObject(cookie.getPath());
        out.writeObject(cookie.getPortlist());
        out.writeInt(cookie.getVersion());
        out.writeBoolean(cookie.getSecure());
        out.writeBoolean(cookie.getDiscard());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String name = (String) in.readObject();
        String value = (String) in.readObject();
        clientCookie = new HttpCookie(name, value);
        clientCookie.setComment((String) in.readObject());
        clientCookie.setCommentURL((String) in.readObject());
        clientCookie.setDomain((String) in.readObject());
        clientCookie.setMaxAge(in.readLong());
        clientCookie.setPath((String) in.readObject());
        clientCookie.setPortlist((String) in.readObject());
        clientCookie.setVersion(in.readInt());
        clientCookie.setSecure(in.readBoolean());
        clientCookie.setDiscard(in.readBoolean());
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may work ... have you considered whether the user wants to allow all cookies to be accepted and allowed them control over this?!

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution will not survive application restarts.  Here's an answer with some basic code to persist in SharedPreferences, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349266/how-do-i-persist-cookies-when-using-httpurlconnection?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @ErstwhileIII: Yes, the users know that and want to stay logged into my service. They can, of course, manually log out any time.

Comment: @Miguel Lavigne: For some reason, it stopped working now, but I'll look into your link. Thank you!

Comment: Great answer, but based on this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/980387) the URI should not be used if the domain and path attributes of the cookies are available.
Also in SerializedCookie the HttpCookie httpOnly attribute is not serialized (it does not have accessors nor mutators).
I have prepared an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27161496/980387) that solves both issues.

Comment: Note these two classes DO persist cookies.   Answer was updated after comment was made (hence the contradiction)

Answer (score 22):

You can set your CookieStore in the OkHttp client with the following code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setCookieHandler(new CookieManager(
                       new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext()),
                       CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
```

I made a [gist with my implementation of a persistent CookieStore](https://gist.github.com/franmontiel/ed12a2295566b7076161) trying to improve [janoliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25462286/980387) in two points:

1. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/980387) the URI should not be used if the domain and path attributes of the cookies are available.
2. In SerializableHttpCookie class the HttpCookie httpOnly attribute is not serialized (it does not have accessors nor mutators). My solution was to use reflection to be able to access this private attribute.

Comment: Just a question about usage of OkHttpClient. Should it be persistent (static) for each request or should I create a fresh new one for each request?

Comment: @StErMi you should be using the same instance for all the requests. Check Jakes Wharton's response to this post (plus.google.com/118239425803358296962/posts/5nzAvPaitHu)

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than the accepted answer.  I'm using it with Retrofit and it works great.

Comment: Proguard and reflection doesn't mix well, so adding '-keep public class package.SerializableHttpCookie { *; }' to your proguard config helps.

Comment: for okhttp3, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881775/automatic-cookie-handling-with-okhttp-3