# Android correct way to use OKHTTP singleton for parallel queries with cookies

Tags: android, cookies, android-networking, okhttp

I am working on an android project in which I am planning to replace Apache httpclient implementation with OKHTTP client. I would like to know how I can create a global Client that can be used for networking requests in different activities and services that will use the multi-threading of client. Should I create a singleton object of OKHTTPClient and reuse it in my code?

Also, where should I add the cookiestore to the request, In the global definition of client so that I all requests will have cookie available or while forming the request in individual activity or service?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The general approach to using OkHttp is one OkHttp instance with one HttpResponseCache instance.  Whether it needs to be created as a singleton depends on the requirements of your application.  For example, the single instance of OkHttp can be created in a subclass of Android's Application.onCreate(), in which case it doesn't need to be a singleton if you make your Android app's subclass of the Application class a singleton.

Quote from their [wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes):

> "Most applications should call new OkHttp() exactly once, configure it
>   with their cache, and use that same instance everywhere. "

Once you have created your OkHttp instance, you can use their `setCookieHandler()` API method to add a persistent cookie store, which will be used in all subsequent HTTP requests.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161496/923920) for further details on implementing a cookiestore that works with OkHttp.

Comment: For completeness sake, the rest of the docs: "Otherwise the two cache instances will stomp on each other, corrupt the response cache, and possibly crash your program."

Comment: What if I am not interested in caching at all?